# Display Powerpress media url

Tags: plugins, theme-development, customization, media

I am trying to display the url of a media file in a template. I ran across this post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-media-url-only, but when I add that to my template (in the loop as it says) nothing shows.

So, I am not sure which is easier...to display what the field in the WordPress admin panel is in the template which looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="powerpress_url_general" class="powerpress-url" name="Powerpress[general][url]" value="myfile.mp3" style="width: 70%;">
```

or to try something like: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-media-url-only (maybe a function has changed).

This is what I have that doesn't output anything:

```
if( function_exists('powerpress_get_enclosure_data') ) {
    $EpisodeData = powerpress_get_enclosure_data($post->ID);
    if( $EpisodeData ) {
        $url = $EpisodeData['url'];
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't the code I have output the url I am looking for?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($EpisodeData)` before the if statement?

Comment: bool(false) is what shows

Comment: It should ask to plugin author, BUT since you have `$post->ID` in your code, I need to ask, is your code in the loop? how the loop code look like?

Comment: The code I am using looks like: http://pastebin.com/MBGp6L8W

Comment: So, after looking into this a little, it seems like this is a little tougher than I initially envisioned. What I'd like to do is simply disable the mobile player and use the same player that the regular site uses on mobile...would that be easier? I figured outputting the url and creating my own player might be easier, now I'm not so certain.

Comment: Maybe.. but if you need to follow your issue, you could search inside plugin files, since it show false in return, you may start to lookup function `powerpress_get_enclosure_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have no idea how it happened, maybe it's a PowerPress thing...I activated the HTML 5 player, then went back and reactivated MediaElement's player and the issue resolved itself. Now, everything looks as expected on mobile.

Thanks,
Josh